# Android Spinner to change text size doesn't save state

Tags: java, android, xml, android-spinner

```
  private void onTextSizeSeekBarChange() {
        final TextView tutorialText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tutorialText);
        final SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        sb.setMax(20);
        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int p = 0;
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                p = progress;
                tutorialText.setTextSize(p);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }


            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                if (p < 20) {
                    sb.setProgress(p);
                }
            }

        });
        }
```

So the problem is that the code I have above changes the text size of a text view. However when going back and forth the state isn't saved so the text size is then reset. I am really new to android and would appreciate any guidance or help on how I can achieve this. I basically have a tutorial app and the text needs to change from the settings menu which has a seekbar allowing the user to select what text size they want. Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you post your activity class code here

Comment: Use **sharedPreference** to save state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have set `sb.setMax(20);` then you dose not need to

`if (p < 20) {
    sb.setProgress(p);
}`

code is useless user cant seek more then **20**

you have code like that

```
  private void onTextSizeSeekBarChange() {
    final TextView tutorialText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tutorialText);

    SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(CONTEXT);
    int p = SP.getInt("key", p);
    tutorialText.setTextSize(p);

    final SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    sb.setMax(20);
    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            p = progress;
            tutorialText.setTextSize(p);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                sb.setProgress(p);
                Editor edit = SP.edit();
                edit.putInt("key", p);
                edit.commit();
        }

    });
    }
```

Comment: The above doesn't appear to work so I have a few questions. Firstly in

Comment: SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(CONTEXT); This shows an error what is CONTEXT?

Comment: int p shows as being uninitialized despite being initialised in int p = SP.getInt("key", p);

Comment: CONTEXT is  `Context`

Answer (score 1):

You can do either in this way :
1)you can save the value of p in shared pref and when you come next time you will check the value of p and set it on textview
2)you can save the value in onSavedInstance,but the problem is that when user kill the app from background you are going to loose the value